# How do i fill in void space's with poly's?

Tags: modeling

[image: image of poly head]I am poly modeling a head and I was wondering if there was a shortcut to insert poly's into this blank space.
I have tried watching video tutorials but I dont see anything useful.

Comment: hello, what do you mean by "insert poly's into this blank space"?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Both sides that you want to connect have the same amount of vertices.

Step 1: select both edges like shown in image 1.

Step 2: Use "Bridge Edge Loops" (available in the edge menu (ctrl+e) or through the search function (F3 or space depending settings))

Step 3: Check for any problems

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Answer (score 2):

There is an add on included called F2. You need to go to Edit > Preferences >Add-ons and turn it on, with this you can select for example, 2 edges and press <kbd>F</kbd> to create a new polygon. Not sure if that's what you are looking for, but, here is an example (minute 1:29) :https://youtu.be/q1fEtys-RII?t=89

Comment: Hello :). Just to clarify, it works even without the F2 addon, it's a basic Blender functionality.